# Delivery errors not appearing for ESP, but Google Postmaster lists a high amount of errors

Tags: email, bulk-email

I saw that our emails had a high delivery error rate on Postmaster over 3 days. However, clicking on the data point returns "No delivery errors for {{date}}" and I cannot find any delivery errors in the data returned by our ESP data either. Our spam rate, encryption, and FBL don't show anything abnormal. The email that was sent out was a previously successful campaign with our higher-quality users.

Has anyone seen a spike in delivery errors without any errors attached? Is there a way to identify these if they aren't provided by Google or the ESP?

[image]